# How to run node-canvas on heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, canvas

I've created a discord bot with node.js that uses a npm called canvas which is running version 2.6.1 but when I wen't to push my files to github and deploy I keep getting faced with errors. If this helps I'm running one buildpack which is the default node.js one.

I've tried using a buildpack that you can find here: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation:-Heroku but that doesn't work.

```
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.18.3
       Using default npm version: 6.14.6
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Prebuild detected (node_modules already exists)
       Rebuilding any native modules
       
       > canvas@2.6.1 install /tmp/build_3c59f676_/node_modules/canvas
       > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
       
       sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
       npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 126
       npm ERR! canvas@2.6.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 126
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.6.1 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.AGHnL/_logs/2020-08-11T12_04_57_845Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - node_modules checked into source control
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Any reason to this and how I can fix this? I've been struggling on this for around an hour or so now.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue with a discord bot. I have the same problem, it works locally, but trying to run it on my server does not work. I tried to push the version without the specific question and got the error for another package. So maybe it has something to do with npm and not with the package itself, but I don't know

Comment: Try installing `node-pre-gyp` I don't believe this is a heroku error, install it then add the new package json and package.lock.json and push it to the heroku server. Don't forget to make a `.gitignore` and include node modules. Let me know if this fixes it